calculate earned fees, total earned fees for LP's on Orca
I want to calculate earned fees for my position and total earned fees for my positions range, but i would be happy to find out how to convert any single fee_growth value to a human readable value like e.g. SOL tokens
From what i found so far for Uniswap v3 the fees are calculated as follows:
for token a when position in range:
fees_token_a = position.liquidity * fee_delta_a / 2**128
with
fee_delta = fee_inside - position.checkpoint_fee_growth_a
fee_inside = fee_growth_global - fee_outside_lower - fee_outside_upper
I've tried this with my own and other random positions and i never got plausible values
Does anybody know how to convert fee_growth values/How to calculate the fees that have been accumulated in a specific price range over some time? This is for the Orca DEX specifically
Thanks in advance
